Reading memory temperatures with i2c-tools
I am trying to read the temperatures of two DDR4 SDRAMS on my motherboard via Ubuntu 22. I can reach these memory temperatures with the HwInfo program on Windows, but the with i2c-tools on Ubuntu can't. I followed these steps for reading on Ubuntu: Options for accessing DDR4 DRAM memory temperature sensors?
When I scan with i2cdetect, there is no change in the i2c addresses displayed when I remove and insert one or two of the memories. As far as I understand, my memories are not detected at all. I try to read the displayed addresses just in case. Although their labels are temperatures, it was clear that they were not memory addresses.
When i run decode-dimms the eeprom driver says the detected dimm does not exist:
“Number of SDRAM DIMMs detected and decoded: 0“
While trying it with ee1004 and at24, it returns a hardware not supported error:
“No eeprom found, the kernel probably does not support your hardware.”
Does anyone have any ideas why decode-dimms is  return zero ​​and i2cdetect isn't able to detect i2c addresses?
